# Cron job doesn't execute php script when located in documents folder

Tags: php, terminal, cron

I'm trying to run a php script using crontab on MacOS. The PHP script is located at /Users/dan/documents/script.php and looks like this:

```php
<?php
file_put_contents('/users/dan/documents/hello.txt', 'Hello there', FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

I then create a cron job to execute the script every minute:

```
* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php /Users/dan/documents/script.php
```

But the script does not execute, so I modified the cron job to log any errors:

```
* * * * * /opt/homebrew/bin/php -f /Users/dan/documents/script.php >> /Users/dan/documents/cron.txt 2>&1
```

I get "Could not open input file: /Users/dan/documents/script.php".

But if I run the php script from outside the documents folder, e.g. from /Users/dan/script.php, then create a cron job to execute it, it executes the script without any issues.

Guessing this could be some permissions issue on the documents folder?

Comment: The cron user may not have permissions to execute in the documents directory. Check the permissions.

Comment: Does MacOS care about the difference between `users` and `Users`? You're using both here.

Comment: @aynber where do I check permissions?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't believe MacOS cares about `users` vs `Users`. Both work.

Comment: In terminal you can see permissions. `ls -lha /Users/dan/documents/script.php`

Comment: @user3783243 my permissions look like this: `-rw-r--r--  1 dan  staff   125B 23 Oct 14:25 /Users/dan/documents/script.php`

Comment: So only Dan can read and write to it. Staff can read it, as can other users. No one can execute it. Might be `chmod +x /Users/dan/documents/script.php` haven't worked with permissions on mac much